# Python Selenuim Alert Box Disable?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-inspector

**How can I tell selenium to press cancel in this case or remove the whole box completely. I looked around and only really saw C# answers. Thank you for your time :)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, it seems like that's an Alert.

In `Python-Selenium` you could do this:

```
Alert = driver.switch_to.alert
Alert.dismiss()
```

However, It could be a pop-up in **HTMLDOM** as well. In this case, you will have to find the right locator `(CSS, XPath etc.)` and perform a click on that cancel button.

Comment: I cant do a Xpath bc its like a chrome thing but I tried using the Alert.dismiss() but I got an error I may be jsut using it wrong but I jsut wanna get another set of eyes on the error https://pastebin.com/g5EtAVJy

Comment: It's Spotify so it must be a public URL? How did you get that alert?

Comment: I get the alreat by visting my playlist https://open.spotify.com/playlist/7be3tcAeBxPwZrKiPcGNPz?si=5d035e77e63f4ce7 and it asks if I want to use the app which I dont.

Comment: I tried to open the URL, however I don't see any alert or pop up. Are you using desktop app or web app?

Comment: Well I do have the dekstop app isntalled but Im jsut using the link on the website

Comment: I am not able to reproduce that alert at my end, however you can try to put some sleep before that switch to alert code and see if that helps.

Comment: Also, you could try to add options, like this:

`options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()`
`options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2})` 
`options.add_argument("--disable-notifications");`

and then invoke the browser driver 

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driver_path, options = options)`

Comment: I already had the Chrome Options in just added the experimental option and arugemnt and didnt seem to work and if u really want to you could download spotify from microft store and it will show but you dont have to do that

Comment: what should I do